# Score terms by field type in a document

Tags: solr

I'm indexing several different fields in a document using Apache SOLR 3.6.

When I do a search for a term, SOLR returns all the occurrences of the term in each field. However, the same score for all the fields that the term occurred inside the text of the field does not change. For example if USC occurred in the title field, and in the contents field, they both get the same score.

Is there a way to index a document of different fields and have a weighted score based on the type of field within the document?

Answer (score 2):

use dismax or edismax and set the qf (query field) parameter to something like this to give the title more weight than the body.

`qf=title^3 body`